# Issue with Alert dialog with two buttons Cancel and Open Link Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, dialog, android-dialog

I use an *Alert* class where I define all alert dialogs to show status message to the user.
This because is more comfortable to manage.

A typical dialog defined in this class is

```
public static void DataCleared(Context con) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(con);
    builder.setTitle(R.string.data_cleared_title);
    builder.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info);
    DialogListner listner = new DialogListner();
    builder.setMessage(R.string.data_cleared_text);
    builder.setPositiveButton("ok", listner);

    AlertDialog diag = builder.create();
    diag.show();
}
```

This dialog has an ok button that when is clicked close the dialog.

I show these dialog in whatever activity simply calling

```
Alerts.DataCleared(MyActivity.this)
```

Now, in the same way I want to create a dialog with two buttons a *Cancel* button to close the dialog and a *Market* button to open a link to another Google Play App

I have tried

```
public static void TryThisApp(Context con) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(con);
    builder.setTitle(R.string.my_title);
    builder.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info);
    builder.setMessage(R.string.my_text)
       .setCancelable(false)
       .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
               Intent marketIntent = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                        Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.myapp.sample"
                                + getPackageName()));
                startActivity(marketIntent);
           }
       })
       .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.cancel();
           }
       });
    AlertDialog diag = builder.create();
    diag.show();
}
```

But doesn't work, get  various compilation error "Cannot make a static reference to the non static method..."

`getPackageName()` and `startActivity(marketIntent);` are underlined red by Eclipse, with this message

How could I fix this issue?
How could I create a dialog with open link and cancel button?

Comment: which line does your compilation error point to? perhaps add a comment on your above code with that info?

Comment: getPackageName())); and  startActivity(marketIntent); are underlined red with the message "Cannot make a static reference to the non static method..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) You have to invoke `getPackageName()` and `startActivity()` on a Context because are instance methods,

2) If you want to do this from another class have to declare `Context con` as final since security policies doesn't allow to refer a non final variable inside an inner class defined in a different method.

3) (isn't obligated) you should invert the buttons, usually *Cancel* is on the left and *Confirm* on the right

This is the right code:

```
public static void TryThisApp(final Context con) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(con);
    builder.setTitle(R.string.my_title);
    builder.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info);
    builder.setMessage(R.string.my_text)
       .setCancelable(false)
       .setPositiveButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
 dialog.cancel();

           }
       })
       .setNegativeButton("Market", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
               Intent marketIntent = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                        Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.myapp.sample"
                                + con.getPackageName()));
                con.startActivity(marketIntent);
           }
       });
    AlertDialog diag = builder.create();
    diag.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The compile-time error here is just that `getPackageName()` `and startActivity()` are both instance methods (from Context). You want to be calling `con.getPackageName()` (i.e., your Context argument) and `con.startActivity()`.

Comment: get another error "cannot refer to the non final variable inside an inner class defined in a different method"

Comment: sounds like you'll want to define another Context object with the final modifier, and initialize it to point at con

Comment: you have simply to add final attribute to passed Context. Below I have posted the whole solution.